# Angular взаимодействие компонентов на одной странице

Tags: angular2, rxjs

Есть страница на которой отображается каталог товаров и корзина для них. При нажатии на кнопку "купить", данные о товаре добавляются в `localstorage`, но компонент корзины не обновляется (только после F5).

Как сделать так, чтобы он обновлялся автоматически? Видимо нужно создать сервис и сделать `Observable`, но не понимаю как именно реализовать.

catalog:

```
  <div class="content">
<div class="item" *ngFor="let auto of auto; let i=index">
    <div> <img src="../../assets/db/{{auto.photo}}" alt=""></div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>{{auto.name}} - {{auto.price}} руб.</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Купить" (click)="toCart(i)"></p></div> 
</div>

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  auto: any;
cart=[];
price=[];

constructor(private service:DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getItems();
}
getItems(){
  this.service
     .getItems()
     .subscribe(goods => {
       this.auto = goods;
     } )
}

toCart(i){
  this.cart.push(this.auto[i]);
  this.price.push(this.auto[i].price);
  localStorage.setItem("cart",JSON.stringify(this.cart));
  localStorage.setItem("price",JSON.stringify(this.price));

}
```

cart component:

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
list = localStorage.getItem("cart");
names = JSON.parse(this.list);
len = this.names.length;
price = this.names.price;
Message: string;   


constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() { 
 }

send(){
  this.Message = "Готово";
  localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(""));
 }  


}
```

cart template:

```
<div class="content">
<li *ngFor="let name of names; let i=index">
  <p>{{name.name}} - {{name.price}}руб.</p>
</li>
<p>Количество: {{len}}  </p>
{{Message}}
<p><input type="submit" value="Оформить заказ" (click)="send()"></p>
```

Comment: У вас были противоречивые формулировки - "но не компонента корзины не обновляются" и "чтобы она обновлялась автоматически". Проверте мою правку. Я правильно понял смысл сказаного?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея в том, что в расшареном между компонентами сервисом.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
```

Имеется поле - хранитель значения, которым хочется обменяться между компонентами и Observable представление этого поля.

```
// Observable boolean
private triggerSource = new Subject<boolean>();

// Observable boolean stream
trigger = this.triggerSource.asObservable();

// Service commands
announce(value: boolean) {
  this.trigger.next(value);
}
```

Далее, компонента, которая хочет поймать событие, что данные доступны, "подписывается" на Observable.

```
this.subscription = myService.trigger.subscribe(
  triggerSource => {
    if (triggerSource)
    ...
});
```

А компонента, котора порождает событие, инициирует Observable.

```
this.myService.announce(true)
```

Тем самым вызывая выполнение тела функции в trigger.subscribe.

Так можно кратко описать пример, который можно найти здесь -> https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.
А для большего понимания магии происходящего, рекомендую поискать что-нибудь по реактивному программированию.